# How to catch errors in JS when using router request

Tags: javascript, express, error-handling

I'm a self taught python backend dev. As always happens we need a little JS doing while the JS dev is on holiday. Help!

I have a JS function that calls our python (aws lambda) backend and links our backend to an external backend. Currently it all works fine but the small issue is if our backend sends an error response the JS function ignores it and sends out the all ok to the other backend. How can I catch and handle the error in JS? I'm assuming I need to put something in before the `.then(res.send({ success: "User has been invited. Please refresh your browser." }))` bit?

Function:

```
router.post('/user/actions/invite', Liana.ensureAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    const userId = req.body.data.attributes.ids[0];  
    const user = await models.user.findByPk(userId);  
    const userCognitoId = user.cognitoId;  
    if (userCognitoId != null){
        res.status(400).send({ error: 'The user has already been sent an invite!' }); 
     } else {
         var options = {
         url: API_URL + '/admin/user/invite', 
         headers: {  
         'Secret-Key': process.env.SECRET_KEY  
         },  
         method: 'POST',  
         form: JSON.stringify({'user_id': userId})  
     };  
     request(options).then(res.send({  
         success: "User has been invited. Please refresh your browser."  
     }));  
     }  
});
```

TIA :)

Comment: Are you using express or something similar to do the post request?

Comment: It is most likely express. I added the tag

Comment: what's the HTTP status code that your backend sends in case it was an error?

Comment: I'm not sure where the request bit comes from but at the top of the file it's defined as `var request = require('request');` like I say I really know very little JS :/
Our backend sends a 400 with details of why the request failed (usually that the username is already in use)

Comment: edit: just spotted this at the top `const router = express.Router();` so I guess it's express

Comment: posted the same question on reddit and was suggested I try something like
```.then((err, response) => { 
   if (response.statusCode == 400){
      res.status(400).send({ error: response.body });
   } else {
      res.send({success: "User has been invited. Please refresh your browser."});
   }
})```
That look about right?